# MQTT server disconnected in swift 3.1

Tags: ios, sockets, swift3, mqtt

I am trying to create a mqtt socket connection using https://github.com/emqtt/CocoaMQTT. Server gets connected but soon after that gets disconnected, giving an error: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}. My code to configure server is:

```
let clientID = "CocoaMQTT-" + String(ProcessInfo().processIdentifier)
self.mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientID, host: "cabs.jellyfishtele.com", port: 61612)
self.mqtt?.willMessage = CocoaMQTTWill(topic: "new", message: "someMessage")
self.mqtt?.keepAlive = 10
self.mqtt?.backgroundOnSocket = true
self.mqtt?.secureMQTT = true
self.mqtt?.cleanSession = true
self.mqtt?.delegate = self
self.mqtt?.connect()
```

Above code is in viewDidLoad. I'm getting connection acknowledgement in didConnectAck method. I want to sustain that connection so as to receive run time messages and display them. Please help!

Console Log:

```
didConnect cabs.jellyfishtele.com:61612
Delegate: mqttDidDisconnect
Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}
```

My Delegate functions:

```
func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceive trust: SecTrust, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    self.mqtt?.allowUntrustCACertificate = true

    completionHandler(true)
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnect host: String, port: Int) {
    print("didConnect \(host):\(port)")
    mqtt.subscribe("topic1")
//        mqtt.ping()
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck){
    print("didConnectAck: \(ack)，rawValue: \(ack.rawValue)")

    if ack == .accept {
        mqtt.subscribe("topic1", qos: CocoaMQTTQOS.qos1)
    }
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
    print("didPublishMessage with message: \(message.string!)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishAck id: UInt16) {
    print("didPublishAck with id: \(id)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16 ) {
    print("didReceivedMessage: \(message.string!) with id \(id)")

}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didSubscribeTopic topic: String) {
    print("didSubscribeTopic to \(topic)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didUnsubscribeTopic topic: String) {
    print("didUnsubscribeTopic to \(topic)")
}

func mqttDidPing(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
    print("didPing")
}

func mqttDidReceivePong(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
    _console("didReceivePong")
}

func mqttDidDisconnect(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, withError err: Error?) {
    _console("mqttDidDisconnect")
    print(err!)
//        mqtt.autoReconnect = true
}

func _console(_ info: String) {
    print("Delegate: \(info)")
}
```

Comment: Not enough info here really, after how long is the connection closed, is the app always in the foreground? Any logs from the broker about why it disconnected the client?

Comment: @hardillb I've updated my question with log and delegate functions. mqttDidDisconnect is printed to the log right after didConnect. I am unable to sustain the connection.

Comment: help please! I'm implementing mqtt for the first time.